# How can I solve this CSS links inheritance problem?

Tags: css, inheritance, hyperlink

It's stumped me an I've tried a couple of things - then again I'm not very experienced so I may just be going about it the wrong way. Basically I want to have different link styles for both the navigation and the pagination. The #navigation styling is overriding my .pagination styling though, and it doesn't appear to matter if the pagination is a class or an ID. I've also tried putting !important in the pagination styling, but this then makes the navigation inherit the pagination (been using firebug to check the inheritance).

```
#navigation a:active, a:link, a:visited, a, a:focus {
color: #ffde2f;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 24px;
text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation a:hover {
color: #ffffff;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 24px;
text-decoration: none;
} 

.pagination a:active, a:link, a:visited, a, a:focus {
color: #fff;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
text-decoration: none;
}

.pagination {
color: #fff;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this change

```
.pagination a:active, a:link, a:visited, a, a:focus {
```

to

```
.pagination a:active, 
.pagination a:link, 
.pagination a:visited, 
.pagination a, 
.pagination a:focus {
```

Comment: Thanks, tried the others but it was still acting a bit strange and inheriting the #navigation styling - tried this and it works a treat! Cheers again

Answer (score 0):

Change #navigation, use a class on the tag rather than style on the ID. Styling by ID is more specific, hence gets higher precendence in styling.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors):

```
#navigation > a
{
  ...
}

.pagination > a
{
  ...
}
```

It is not supported by IE6, but it is dying.